# Laravel 5 fetching data from database using eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have written a member function like ::

```
public function details($article_seo){
        $articleDet = Articles::where(function($query) {
            $query->where('article-seo', '=', $article_seo);
            })
        ->get();
        dd($articleDet);
    }
```

and have used these at the beginning of laravel controller::

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\articles;  /** this is the eloquent model **/
```

The problem is ::
when ever i try to pass the `$article_seo` that I am receiving from the url data, it gives me an eror of ::: `Undefined variable: article_seo`

Being new to Laravel i have checked out lot of ways but unable to find one.Please help!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use an outside variable inside of a closure, you have pass the variable into the closure using the `use` keyword.

```
public function details($article_seo){
        $articleDet = Articles::where(function($query) use ($article_seo) {
            $query->where('article-seo', '=', $article_seo);
            })
        ->get();
        dd($articleDet);
    }
```

You can get Articles match with your article-seo easily.

```
    public function details($article_seo){
        $articleDet = Articles::where('article-seo', '=', $article_seo)
        ->get();
        dd($articleDet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Closures aren't necessary here, you can simple use the model's where method to do what you are looking for.

```
$details = Articles::where('article-seo', '=', $article_seo)->get();
```

Cleaning that up a little bit, the where expression will use an equal sign by default, so we can omit that.

```
$details = Articles::where('article-seo', $article_seo)->get();
```

If your database values were snake cased (article_seo instead of article-seo), then you can simplify that expression even more

```
$details = Articles::whereArticleSeo($article_seo)->get();
```

That is a whole lot easier to read than the original closure based method!

Comment: thank you  too for the help, both the method were helpful, being new to Laravel it helped me explore both way functions